# How to avoid duplicate enum values in java?

Tags: java, enums

I have enum which corresponds to encodings.I need to check that enum don't have repeating number values for encodings.

```
public enum EncodingsEnum
{

ISO8859_1("ISO-8859-1",0), ISO8859_2("ISO-8859-2",1),
    ISO8859_3("ISO-8859-3",2), ISO8859_4("ISO-8859-4",3),
    ISO8859_5("ISO-8859-5",4), ISO8859_6("ISO-8859-6",5),
    ISO8859_7("ISO-8859-7",6), ISO8859_8("ISO-8859-8",7),
    ISO8859_9("ISO-8859-9",8), ISO8859_11("ISO-8859-11",9),
    ISO8859_13("ISO-8859-13",10),ISO8859_15("ISO-8859-15",11),
    UTF_8("UTF-8",11);

    public static final int ENCODINGS_COUNT = EncodingsEnum.values().length;
    private final String encodingName;
    private final int encodingNumber;

    EncodingsEnum(final String encodingName,int encodingNumber)
    {
        ReferenceChecker.checkReferenceNotNull(encodingName);

        this.encodingName = encodingName;
        this.encodingNumber = encodingNumber;
    }

    public static String getEncodingNameByNumber(int number)
    {
        for(EncodingsEnum encoding : EncodingsEnum.values())
        {
            if(encoding.encodingNumber == number)
            {
                return encoding.getEncodingName();
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Encoding with this number isn't supported:" + number);

    }

    public static int getEncodingNumberByName(final String name)
    {
        for(EncodingsEnum encoding : EncodingsEnum.values())
        {
            if(encoding.encodingName.equals(name))
            {
                return encoding.getEncodingNumber();
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Encoding with this name isn't supported:" + name);
    }

    public String getEncodingName()
    {
        return this.encodingName;
    }

    public int getEncodingNumber()
    {
        return this.encodingNumber;
    }
}
```

There is a problem that I can create encoding with the same number as one of the existing encodings,so I need to check that enum contains element with this number and throw exception.But I dont know how to do that.Any idea?Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "I can create encoding with the same number as one of the existing encodings"? The contents of `EncodingsEnum.java` at compile time is final - you cannot create new `enum` constants at runtime. Try hitting `Ctrl-f` before adding a new constant.

Comment: Why don't you simply take the ordinal as the number? That way it's guaranteed by the language that it's unique.

Comment: as I know it's a bad practice to use ordinal.

Comment: @AvershinDmitry: yes, but having your own almost-ordinals in an error-prone, manual way is not really much better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This shouldn't be checked at runtime: it would be too late. Add a unit test that iterates through the enum values, and check that they all have a different number. And make sure to always execute the unit tests, and check that they pass, before generating a new version of your application/library.

```
@Test
public void encodingNumbersMustBeUnique() {
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (EncodingsEnum e : EncodingsEnum.values()) {
        assertFalse(numbers.contains(e.getEncodingNumber()));
        numbers.add(e.getEncodingNumber());
    }
}
```

Comment: "Too late" - and incredibly wasteful.  Why keep checking it over and over again?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this code.

```
public enum EncodingsEnum {
     ONE(1),
     TWO(1);

     private int number;

     static {
      if (!test()) {
       throw new RuntimeException();
      }
     }

     private EncodingsEnum(int number) {
      this.number = number;
     }

     public static boolean test() {
      final Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();

      for (final EncodingsEnum enc : EncodingsEnum.values()) {
       numbers.add(enc.number);
      }

      return numbers.size() == EncodingsEnum.values().length;
     }
```

Comment: This works, but is not executed always when the application is loaded. I used this way, but doing it in a unit test is better, as in the currently accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11467629/822870

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you can iterate through the encodingNumbers of the enum and throw an exception if you find a duplicate. Something like this:

```
public boolean isPresent(String type){
            ClassType[] typeArray = ClassType.values();
            for(ClassType cType: typeArray){
                if(cType.absoluteName/*this is some private field of the class*/.equalsIgnoreCase(type)){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Put the above check just before you are assigning number and name in your constructor. If the check returns true, throw an exception else not.

Comment: Calling `ClassType.values();` in the constructor throws a NullPointerException (in Java 1.6; I'm working on some old project, will try newer versions too).

Comment: Same in Java 11.